# How do i get the manage jenkins button?

Tags: jenkins

[image]I am new to jenkins. My jenkins is running on a remote server. In my dash-board, all the options are there except for the following buttons.

> Manage Jenkins
>
> Credentials

How do I get them ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you logging in as admin? Or with full permissions?